# How to make a multi-steps registration page with multi ContentView?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

In the app I'm working on, there's  a multi-steps registration, 4 steps:
to accomplish it, I'm thinking to have a single page to host a content view of the registration step, when it passes the validation requirements I remove it  and inject the next content view.
This is an example to simplify my need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamApp"
             x:Class="XamApp.MainPage">
        <local:Register1/>
</ContentPage>
```

and the Register1 looks like this:

```
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamApp"
                 x:Class="XamApp.Register1">
        <ContentView.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="intToBool"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentView.Resources>
        <ContentView.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Page 1" FontSize="Large"/>
                <Entry x:Name="txtName" Placeholder="Name"/>
                <Button Text="Next" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtName},
                                        Path=Text.Length,
                                        Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

**There are two problems:**

1- I don't know how to handle the data (view model) between steps, to have only one object through all steps **(Shall I use DI? if yes , then how in MVVMLight?)**

2- How to to inject the content view into the main registration page dynamically in an MVVM fashion?

Comment: Create multiple contentView and change them at runtime as per conditions or on certain events, its like a piece of cake with convertors

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with, is creating an interface:

```
    public interface INavigate
    {
        INavigate Next();
        INavigate Previous();
    }
```

all the `ContentView`s inherit from, for example the second `ContentView` implementation:

```
    public INavigate Next()
    => new View3();

    public INavigate Previous()
    => new View1();
```

the container page's `Content` property is bound to the view model's property `CurrentView` of type `INavigate`, 
the command of the next button execute this:

```
CurrentView = CurrentView.Next();
```

and this is for the previous button:

```
CurrentView = CurrentView.Previous();
```